# intellij idea 14 code style xml can't find in mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am trying to import new code style xml into intellij Idea 14. I created a new code style with name `wso2_codestyle`. But I can't find it in anywhere in Mac. I have installed Yosemite OS.

Where I can find the created `wso2_codestyle.xml` file?

Comment: Try [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) - freeware Much easier than Spotlight for finding system files etc.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac (running Yosemite), the custom IntelliJ codestyle XMLs go in `~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14/codestyles/`